# Node js passport local authentication is keep on loading

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am creating an app with node js (express and mysql), trying to do authentication with passport local. when i click on log in, everything running fine but after comparing credentials success redirect not working (**keep loading**). but if credentials not matched then failure redirect is working fine **without any error**.

**what is wrong? where? can anyone help to find out? please...**

my login route:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => { 
       console.log('post login.');          //never logged, why?
    passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect: '/admin/dashboard',
      failureRedirect: '/login',
      failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

passport config:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Load User model
const User = require('../config/db').User;

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email',  passwordField: 'password' }, (username, password, done) => {
      // Match user
      User.findOne({where: {email: username}}).then(user => {

        console.log(user.name);        //logged user name.

        if (!user) {

          return done(null, false, { message: 'That email is not registered' });
        }

        // Match password
        const isMatched = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);

          if (isMatched) {
              console.log('password matched.');         //logged when password matched.
            return done(null, user);
          } else { console.log('password not matched.');    //logged when password not matched.
            return done(null, false, { error_msg: 'Password incorrect' });
          } 
      });
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      console.log('serialized: ', user.id);       //logged when credentials matched.
    return done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findByPk(id, function(err, user) {
        console.log('deserialized');

      return done(null, user.id);
    });
  });

};
```

Comment: Have you looked at the docs at http://www.passportjs.org/docs/ ? You are declaring your passport authentication inside of a middleware rather than how the docs specify.

Comment: Yes! I've seen the docs, but can't figure it out. That's why I followed a tutorial for it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours of googling, i found a solution for this, the problem here is in the deserializeUser method.
I just change a little bit of code in the deserializeUser because: **passport can't deserialize the user out of the session**.

It worked well for me, and I hope it will work for someone with a problem like mine.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
      return done(null, user);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When deserializing input the Id and you will return the user object. Do like this

```
 passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        console.log('deserialized');

      return done(null, user);
    });
  });
```